# file upload issue

Tags: php

There are 2 variables in PHP that affects file upload (specially when their is file is too large)

```
1. max_input_time
2. max_execution_time
```

Now I want to know whether max_execution_time is calculated after file upload is done, or it is counted with it?

EDIT: I have one file that is around 25+ MB, now my script execution time will be calculated after file is uploaded to temp directory, or it is considered with the upload process?

Comment: there are more `post_max_size, upload_max_filesize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max_execution_time` does not include the time it takes you to upload a file to the server. It starts running when PHP starts executing (after file uploads).

You can easily test this for yourself using a dash of PHP and FireBug. Add this to your code:

```
var_dump(getrusage());
```

This will show you the resources used by the PHP script. The `ru_utime.tv_sec` and `ru_utime.tv_usec` elements tell you how many seconds and microseconds of execution time have been used so far. So, upload a reasonably large file to your script. Then compare `ru_utime.tv_sec` with the times from the Net panel in firebug.